# Meteor: Make jQuery ajax posts from NodeJs to php

Tags: jquery, node.js, meteor

I am using [this](https://github.com/crazytoad/meteor-collectionapi/blob/master/collectionapi.js) API to perform CRUD database operations in my meteor application. Till now, every operation is performed nicely.

Now consider a use case where some error occurs (eg. some validation error like invalid parameter) then I want to send the error object to the php script through **jQuery ajax call**.

So the question is: How to post the object to php from NodeJs script?

I have tried adding Meteor's default jquery package by `meteor add jquery`. and then done something like this:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
....
....
 function test(data){
   console.log('test'+JSON.stringify(data));
     $.post({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://vibsy.com/test/chest.php',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        } 
     });
  }
```

But this shows the error:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at app\server\collectionapi.js:1:10
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery works well from the client side, im not too sure it will work on the server end. If you performed `meteor add jquery` you don't have to use `require`. Meteor will automatically reference the correct js files ready to use. Remove the line below (client only) and it should be good to go

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

If your script is running on the server, which it looks like it is. Its better to use [Meteor.http](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_http). Run `meteor add http` and use something like:

```
Meteor.http.call("POST", "http://vibsy.com/test/chest.php",{params: data}, function (error, result) {
    if (result.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(result);
    }
 });
```

Or more comfortably (sync):

```
var result = Meteor.http.call("POST", "http://vibsy.com/test/chest.php",{params: data});
if (result.statusCode === 200) {
    console.log(result.data); //JSON content
    console.log(result.content); //raw content
}
```

Comment: I have followed your solution. and the Meteor console shows response as [here](http://jsbin.com/oxifif/1/edit). But there is no activity on php side. I have been inspecting Net panel in firebug, but it remains idle.

Comment: You would have to check the php script, its returning a `Hi` so if somethings not going on its on that end. Did you pass any stuff off in data for the post parameters?

Comment: there is nothing on php side. I just want to  recieve the object posted there from meteor side. Also, I have replaced the `{params: data}` with `obj` which contains `{result: "fail", code:"1001", message: 'Parameter missing'}`.

Comment: You need to use `{params: {result: "fail", code:"1001", message: 'Parameter missing'}}`.

Comment: I think you need to see the PHP end again because it is giving a response to meteor with `Hi` which indicates the request was successful. The problem is more likely on the PHP end. You won't see any results in firebug because it only displays requests sent from the client side